# Calculating value for alpha in ln

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have the following formula:
$$
2((\frac1\alpha)\space ln\frac{1}{(1-\alpha)} )= \frac{1}{1-\alpha}
$$

After applying the ln rules and multiplying I end up with:
$$
(2\alpha-2)\cdot(ln(1-\alpha)=\alpha
$$

How can I find the value of alpha from here? 
I thought of using e^ to cancel out the ln but keep ending up stuck with it again and again.

Comment: The equation has no solution in terms of elementary functions. However it is solvable numerically or using the [Lambert W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

Answer (score 0):

By inspection, $\alpha =0$ is a solution of your second equation. Also, it may be above the level of your course but another solution can be expressed as the [Lambert W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) as $-\exp\left({W\left(-\frac{2}{e^2}\right)+2}\right)$.

Comment: The first equation is not defined for $\alpha =0$.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, I do believe it's above my course's level. Could you perhaps explain how to simplify the equation? Would it be correct to try "cancel" out the ln using e? e.g. make the whole equation: $$e^{2a-2} \cdot(1-a)-e^\alpha=0$$?